# Cycles is not shown in the render engine list

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

Cycles render engine is not shown in the render engine list with EEVEE and Worckbench  as usual.

Why is not there? How can I get it back?

Comment: Hello :). Cycles is simply a Blender addon. Perhaps you disabled it?

Comment: Yes, check to see if the add-on for "Render: Cycles Render Engine" is enabled. Short of that, what graphics card are you using and are the drivers up to date on it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you deleted the cycles render engine add on in preferences. If so I would recommend just redownloading blender from blender.org

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you downloaded a build of Blender that doesn't have Cycles, or you disabled the Cycles add-on by accident

Note posting your system information, Blender version will greatly help.
also it helps if you launch `blender` from command line or terminal and paste the output here.